# How to send customer email on stripe dashboard

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments

I'm trying to send customer email on stripe dashboard.
how to send email on stripe.

```
public function stripePost(Request $request)
    {
        Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
        Stripe\Charge::create ([
            "amount" => 100 * 100,
            "currency" => "usd",
            "source" => $request->stripeToken,
            "customer" => "customerstripe@gmail.com",
            "description" => "Test payment."
        ]);

        Session::flash('success', 'Payment successful!');

        return back();
    }
```

Error is.

```
No Such Customer: customerstripe@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You should ideally be using [Payment Intents](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment) instead of Charges, but in this case you want to use [`receipt_email`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/create#create_charge-receipt_email).